# Nonsingularity of Tangent Bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tangent-bundle

Is it true if $X$ is nonsingular affine variety of dimension $m$ inside $\mathbb{A}^n$ then $TX$, the tangent bundle of $X$ is also nonsingular variety but with dimension $2m$? I have proved it is an algebraic set of dimension $2m$ but I do not know how to prove it is irreducible and it is nonsingular. I tried to compute the rank of Jacobian but did not find the rank.

Edit : idea of my work so far is we have $TX=Z(f_1,\dots,f_r, df_1,\dots, df_r)$ where $X=Z(f_1,\dots,f_r)$. When I computed the Jacobian matrix for $TX$ at some $(p,v) \in X$, I will get lower triangular blocks of matrix,
but I was not able to find its rank. The matrix will be
$\begin{pmatrix}
A & 0\\
B & C
\end{pmatrix}$
with $A$ consists of first derivatives of $f_1,\dots,f_r$ and $B$ consists of second derivatives of same polynomials

Comment: Locally it's just $X\times \Bbb A^n$, so...

Comment: @KReiser how to deduce nonsingularity from that fact?

Comment: Lots of ways! For instance, if $U\subset X$ is an affine open where $TX$ is trivial, then compare the embeddings of $U\subset\Bbb A^m$ and $U\times\Bbb A^n\subset \Bbb A^{m+n}$. If you're trying to see how to deduce it from what you've proven so far, maybe you could show your work with an [edit] to your post.

Comment: @KReiser ok, I will edit my post